# Is there a way to use Single Sign On(SSO) with my-website's account on other websites?

Tags: javascript, php, html, django, single-sign-on

So I want to make an app store like Epic Games(let's name it "AB"). I want that the game developers can integrate my website with their games so they can provide a "Login With AB" option on their login page. Is it possible?
Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Yes it's possible, why not.

Comment: @kiner_shah Please state the method

Answer (score 1):

What you are requesting is an sso (Single sign on), the equivalent of Google sign. YOu need to provide an api to return a refresh/access token from your website, and a way to authenticate the same. Also provide details of the logged in user to the requesting website.
Its actually available in the market as various opensource projects as well.

Readup on OpenID, OAuth2, SSO, Keycloak etc